# ImportError: No module named menu

Tags: python, django, admin, customization

I'm trying to customize the admin interface with django-admin-tools.

I'm following https://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html

The `menu.py` has been created successfully with `python manage.py custommenu` in my project directory.

I have then renamed it to `Mymenu.py`

When I add `ADMIN_TOOLS_MENU = 'project_name.Mymenu.CustomMenu'` to my `settings.py`, as indicated I get the follwoing error: `ImportError: No module named menu`

my settings.py

```
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'admin_tools',
    'admin_tools.theming',
    'admin_tools.menu',
    'admin_tools.dashboard',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'admin_platform',
    'colorful',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
            'loaders': [ 'admin_tools.template_loaders.Loader',
                        ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', [
                                    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
                                    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
                                    ]),

                         ]
        },
    },
]


DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}



# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'static')
STATICFILES_FINDERS = ['django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder']

ADMIN_TOOLS_MENU = 'myProject.Mymenu.CustomMenu'
```

Comment: Is the app in your installed_apps?

Comment: did you import the module? Anyway, please add your code

Comment: You Created the app using the command 

python manage.py startapp custommenu 

right?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it by replacing `ADMIN_TOOLS_MENU = 'project_name.Mymenu.CustomMenu'` simply by `ADMIN_TOOLS_MENU = 'Mymenu.CustomMenu'`

Comment: this should be the answer

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you have created the app using the following command,

```
python manage.py startapp custommenu
```

and then renamed the views.py to Mymenu.py

in that case you need to write `custommenu` in your installed apps instead of `Mymenu`

Comment: no, I'm following https://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/customization.html

Comment: In that case i don't think you need to add it into your installed apps. You need to add django admin tools, check this https://django-admin-tools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html

Comment: yes, I know, there is no need to add it,  I've only added it as an attempt  to solve the error, I updated my question

Comment: Maybe you forgot to create a __init__.py file within the MyMenu project?